# Unexpected Token in JSON error but I'm using 'produces = "text/plain"'?

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I'm getting an error when I call the following function in my web app:

```js
  getUML() {
    const testName = this.formdata.get('testName');
    this.disableDeployCTA = true;
    const params:string = testName + "/txt";
    const url = `http://localhost:8081/bruml/export/${params}`
    this.httpService.generateUML(params).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.umlText = response.data;
    });
  }
```

The request is going through a Spring Boot application, using this method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/export/{testName}/txt", produces = "text/plain")
public ResponseEntity<String> exportTxt(@PathVariable("testName") String name) {
    UMLClient myClient = new UMLClient(); 
    String txtUML = "";
    byte[] toExport = null; 
    try {
        String fileName = ".\\tempFiles\\" + name;
        myClient.export(name, fileName + ".txt", true);
        
        File txtTemp = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        File file = new File(fileName + ".svg");
        Path filePath = Paths.get(fileName + ".txt");
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        txtUML = new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath)); 
        if(file.exists() && txtTemp.exists()) {
            file.delete();
            txtTemp.delete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(txtUML, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

And the generateUML method is below:

```
  generateUML(params) {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8081/bruml/export/'+ params);
  }
```

And Im getting an error that "Unexpected token @ in JSON." But I don't want it to parse as JSON -- I set the produces attribute to plain text. How can I fix this?

EDIT**

I'm getting this error in the console
[image]

And these are the details in my network tab in dev tools regarding the request and response:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you please post your json

Comment: where do you get this error message, on the front end or the backend?

Comment: @Bharat `@startuml 
autonumber 
==step 1: ABS.API== 
"someImport"->"Web API Step 1": API #1 
rnote left "someImport"
static data 1
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 1"
"someImport" <-- "Web API Step 1": [] 
deactivate "Web API Step 1"
@enduml` do wanna note though that I want to produce plain text and not JSON

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar on the front end, in the console!

Comment: yup, then the backend is doing it's job correctly ( to double check this, fire the same thing in postman and check the headers ), the frontend seems to be expecting a JSON object, you might have to dig deeper in the `generateUML` method

Comment: Your JavaScript code defines a `url` variable, then **never use it** for anything. I don't think the code is even hitting that `exportTxt()` handler method.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar double checked in Postman, it sets it to text. my `generateUML` method has the right URL though - its just calling  http://localhost:8081/bruml/export/someImport/txt
by doing  `generateUML(params) {return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8081/bruml/export/'+ params);
  }`

Comment: @Andreas removing it doesnt change anything, when I go to inspect dev tools and into Network, I can see it's making the call in exportTxt(). I can see the response too, it just thinks its supposed to be json

Comment: @anoncomp What is the `Content-Type` header of the response? `text/plain`, right? So the problem is entirely within the `generateUML()` JavaScript method, and since you haven't shared that with us, there is really nothing we can do to help you with that.

Comment: @Andreas added it in!

Comment: @Andreas, now we have a problem with the httpClient object 

Comment: @anoncomp Oh well, looks like you don't really want our help, given that you can't seem to post relevant code. How are we supposed to know what `this.httpClient` is, and how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anoncomp can you post the request and response from your browser network tab and if you are getting `200` response then we can see what exactly you are getting from the backend. If you are getting the correct response then the problem will be in this line:
`this.umlText = response.data;` as you are expecting response to be an object.
You might have to parse response.

EDIT: are you using Angular? If so, can you try sending the option in a `get` request with `responseType` as `text` as well? For reference: [Angular Docs](https://www.angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server). As by default Angular consider response as JSON:

From angular documentation:

> The get() call needs the following options: `{observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'}`.

These are the default values for those options, so the following examples do not pass the options object.

Comment: posted! I got a 200 response, and I also put in all the details I could find about the headers, the response, etc. The response header says plain text, interestingly. How would you instead recommend replacing `this.umlText = response.data`?

Comment: just use this.umlText = response;

Comment: got the same error :( I also tried response.data.toString, and response.text()

Comment: @anon comp are you using angular? If yes can you try sending the option in get request with response type text as well .  For reference: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server as by default Angular consider response as JSON: from angular documentation :
To fetch this kind of data, the get() call needs the following options: {observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'}. These are the default values for those options, so the following examples do not pass the options object.